# Python: First Object from a Json

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x

i got a Json File with some environment variables, which i want to load into my programm, work with them or change them. After that i want to save the variables also into the json.

For that i created a Json File which looks like this:

```
{"1": { "Farbe": "weiss", "Gewicht": "1000", "Preis":30},"2"{....}
```

Now im trying to open the File and to print the Value "Farbe".

```
f = open(my_file)
    filament = json.load(f)
    f.close()
    print (filament)
    pairs = filament.items()
    for key, value in pairs:
        x = key
    print (x)
    i=1
    while i <= len(key):
        print ("\t",i,".) ",filament[i]['Farbe']"\n")
        i=i+1
```

But when i try to got my Value with a varaible i like Filament[i], i cant get an Error like this: `Traceback (most recent call last): File "F:\Python\Tutorial\Datei_druckkosten.py", line 49, in <module> print ("\t",i,".) ",filament[i]['Farbe']) KeyError: 1`

I want that my Result looks like this:

1.) Weiss
2.) Something else
....

Can someone help?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Could you elaborate more on what the expected result should be?

Comment: Why are you iterating over the dict twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must convert in
`enter code here`filament[i]['Farbe']
i
to string
`enter code here`filament[str(i)]['Farbe'] and add a comma
`enter code here`filament[i]['Farbe'], "\n"